# How to Manage Live Data in a Django Powered Project?

Tags: django

Noob here... :)

I'm working on a small and personal project that is already in "production", but development still is under way. In the last weeks I've managed to handle the updates in a hacky way. Usually, I make a dump of the (still small) database into json files, separed by app or sometimes by table, drop everything in the database, implement the model's changes in json level trough scripts, syncdb a new database, and put everything back on. I known, it's dumb, but I'm lacking knowledge of a better alternative. So, now that I'm borderline insane with this strategy I come to you guys.

I've looked into South, but I failed to understand how exactly is it's workflow regarding the Data migration (in opposition of it's schema migration that is obvious).

So, how do you guys do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

South creates python scripts. So you can use South to create schema migrations, and then change these scripts to include your own data migration.

If you just add models and fields you don't need to do this, you can just use plain South.

Comment: So, for what you said, can I understand that South is The tool to be mastered from now on? (I'm barely scratching it's surface :)

Comment: i use it in all my django projects. 1 or 2 years ago there were other tools like South, but now it's the standard de facto